# Как распарсить XML файл в python?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, парсер

Я пытаюсь получить текущий курс доллара:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib3
import xml
import sys

u = urllib3.urlopen("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp", timeout=10)
```

Файл XML_daily.asp содержит:

```
...
<Valute ID="R01215">
<NumCode>208</NumCode>
<CharCode>DKK</CharCode>
<Nominal>10</Nominal> 
<Name>Датских крон</Name> 
<Value>63,8151</Value>
</Valute> 
<Valute ID="R01235">
<NumCode>840</NumCode>
<CharCode>USD</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal> 
<Name>Доллар США</Name> 
<Value>35,0115</Value>
</Valute>
 ...
```

Как мне вытащить отсюда Value для доллара (Valute ID="R01235")?

Comment: Это XML, вот и работайте с этим как с XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('/tmp/XML_daily.asp')
```

Затем вытащить нужную валюту с помощью XPath:

```
tree.findall('./Valute[@ID="R01235"]/Value')[0].text
```

Comment: У меня выводит: `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token):`

Comment: @derkode, не знаю, у меня все работает:
        
        $ curl "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp" > /tmp/XML_daily.asp
        $ python3
        Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 21:31:18) 
        [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
        Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
        >>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
        >>> 
        >>> tree = ET.parse('/tmp/XML_daily.asp')
        >>> tree.findall('./Valute[@ID="R01235"]/Value')[0].text
        '34,9043'

Answer (score 4):

Вот полный Питон скрипт, который печатает текущий курс доллара (слегка упрощённый вариант [dzhioev ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/325393#325456)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlopen
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

with urlopen("https://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp", timeout=10) as r:
    print(etree.parse(r).findtext('.//Valute[@ID="R01235"]/Value'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать модуль re из стандартной библиотеки python: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), или использовать какой-либо парсер, вот тут уже от вкуса и требований зависит. Например, parser или grab.

Comment: За советы парсить *ML регекспами пора уже расстреливать на месте :)