# Как получить курс валют Yahoo в формате json или xml Yahoo Api

Tags: java, android, json, api, yahoo

Кто знает как получить курс валют yahoo? Раньше получал с помошью строки запроса [Yahoo Console](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDUAH%22)&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys), или это [Тоже самое но Json](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDUAH%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=), но теперь они не работают, может кто знает другой способ?

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как распарсить XML файл в python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/325393/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй finance.yahoo.com

в XML:
http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote

в JSON
https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

*Yahoo* закрыли, пользуйтесь [*currate.ru*](https://currate.ru/).

В JSON:

```
GET: https://currate.ru/api/?get=rates&pairs=USDRUB,EURRUB&key=YOUR-API-KEY
```