# Как взять строку с браузера в программу?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. В программирование я совсем новичок (совсем зеленый, так сказать :D)
Ну и вообщем,появилась у меня идея,сделать что то типа конвертера валют. Но записывать и обновлять в ручную текущий курс валют не хочется. Есть ли какой то способ это автоматизировать(брать курс валюты с сайта)?

P.S Извините за заголовок. Ничего умнее не придумал :D

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берёшь api центробанка и в соответствии с [описанием](https://www.cbr.ru/development/SXML/) посылаешь ему запросы.

Понадобится некая библиотека, умеющая посылать запросы по http и получать на них ответ, а также библиотека, умеющая парсить xml.

Есть официальные примеры на VB6 и PHP - их можно взять за основу и переписать на С++.

---

В принципе, можно найти какое-то другое api, например Yahoo:
[Как получить курс валют Yahoo в формате json или xml Yahoo Api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739842/178988)

Comment: А не могли бы вы показать,как должен выглядеть этот код? Бродил всю ночь по гуглу,так ничего и не нашел...

Comment: Неа, не знаю...